# What does "Status" mean in the In App Billing section?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm trying to implement the in app billing service in my app (for test-purposes currently). Have tried to check out resources and documentation but I haven't found any on what the status means and for what purpose.

This is what I'm talking about in the console:

[image]

If I set it as Active, does it mean that I can only make a real transaction?, where as I want to test only. Kindly help me understand this in detail.

Comment: @Bryan Ibrahim, is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the status is inactive, it means that the item won't be available for purchase nor for testing. Whereas if the item is active, it means the product is available for purchase for testing purposes(not published on the play-store) and for commercial purposes(published).

Check out this link [creating a managed product](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481)